# storing the weights used by scipy griddata for re-use

Tags: optimization, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate data from an unstructured mesh **M1** to another unstructured mesh **M2**. For this, `scipy.interpolate.griddata` seems good.

However, I will need to interpolate many times from **M1** to **M2**, changing only the data not the meshes. I guess that, internally, the `scipy.interpolate.griddata` defines some weight coefficients when interpolating from **M1** to **M2** and that this may be one of the expensive parts of the computation.

Therefore, I would like to avoid re-compute these weigths each time. Is there a way to do this? I.e., interpolating many times from one unstructured mesh to another unstructured mesh, both kept constant, avoiding to re-compute the internals of `scipy.interpolate.griddata` (or equivalent)?

Comment: can you help me similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/61098743/13258046

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution is to use the [`LinearNDInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html) Scipy function with a pre-computed [Delaunay](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) triangulation:

```
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator

tri = Delaunay(mesh1)  # Compute the triangulation

# Perform the interpolation with the given values:
interpolator = LinearNDInterpolator(tri, values_mesh1)
values_mesh2 = interpolator(mesh2)
```

`mesh1` is a (number of points * dim) array.

Note: [`CloughTocher2DInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CloughTocher2DInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.CloughTocher2DInterpolator) could be used for non-linear interpolation. `griddata` uses either `LinearNDInterpolator` or `CloughTocher2DInterpolator`.